# Function inside render that's triggering setState

Tags: reactjs

In my `render`, I'm triggering a function to redirect the user to a different page but I get an error `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render)`.

I noticed that if I put the `redirectToPath` function (in `render`) in a `setTimeout`, it allows the state to finish transitioning and the error is gone. It also works if I put `history.push(path)` and `setState` (within `redirectToPath`) in a `setTimeout`. How can I refactor this so I don't have conflicts with the state transition?

```
componentDidMount() {
let branchKeyTest = 'key_test_b'

branch.init(branchKeyTest, (err, data) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 1))

  // save branch deeplink data to localStorage
  if (data && data.data_parsed) {
    switch (data.data_parsed.link_type) {
      case 'new_release':
        localStorage.setItem('redirect', JSON.stringify({
          'link_type': 'new_release',
          'release_id': data.data_parsed.release_id
        }));
        console.log("Redirect path stored to localStorage")
        // this.setState({ redirectPath: localStorage.getItem('redirect') })
        break;
      default:
        console.log("No deeplink data or link type not recognized")
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('redirect') != null) {
      this.setState({ redirectPath: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('redirect')) })
    }
  }
  this.setState({ isLoading: false })
}) 


redirectToPath = (path) => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    localStorage.removeItem('redirect')
    history.push(path);
    this.setState({ redirectPath: null })   
  }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, isOnline, showConnectionWarning, redirectPath } = this.state;
        const { token, location, modal, showLogoutModal } = this.props;
        const loggedIn = !!token;


    if (!isLoading && loggedIn && (redirectPath != null)) {
      console.log("logged in and has redirect local storage")
      switch (redirectPath.link_type) {
        case 'new_release':
          // setTimeout(() => {
          //   this.redirectToPath(`/releases/releaseinfo/${redirectPath.release_id}`)
          // }, 500)
            this.redirectToPath(`/releases/releaseinfo/${redirectPath.release_id}`)
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    }

    if (!isLoading) {
      return (
        <div>Done Loading</div>
      );

    }
    else {
      return (<h1>Loading...</h1>)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a weird way to handle your loading. Maybe you could explain us your logic behind this?

Meanwhile, here something you could give a try

Instead of:

```
<div>Done Loading</div>
```

Use:

```
<Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
```

Please refer to the documentation for working example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: In my `componentDidMount`, I'm waiting for the redirect path data to come back and then saving that data to localStorage and the state. Once it's saved to state, I want to redirect the user to the correct view. I also need to clear state or else it'll continuously try to re-render.

Comment: I'm saving the data to localStorage because if the user is not logged in, they'll be brought to the login screen and I want to retain the data to redirect them after they're logged in.